# Python to retrieve condition based columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have to retrieve all rows from w_loaded_updated_iod.xlsx where on column waived = Yes.

[image]

I have tried this:

```
    import pandas as pd
    excel1 = 'C:/Users/gopoluri/Desktop/Latest/w_loaded_updated_iod.xlsx'
    df1 = pd.read_excel(excel1)
    values1 = df1[0 : 7]
    dataframes = [values1]
    df1.loc[df1['Waived'] == 'Yes'].to_excel("output11.xlsx")
```

But I am getting and all columns. But I need the all rows only from column 2, column 3, column 5, column8. Can anyone please correct my code if anything is wrong.
Like below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can get columns x,y,z from your dataframe by filtering as follows:

```
df = df.loc[["x", "y", "z"]].
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1,2,3],b=[3,4,5],c=[5,6,7]))
df = df[["a","b"]]
df # prints output:

   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  3  5
```

Comment: I need to use the above condition as well. How to use please let me know.